# Attaining the data in json format from the payload which is available as "org.mule.munit.common.util.ReusableByteArrayInputStream@53534c15" in mule 3

Tags: json, mule, dataweave

I need the real payload json data to be able to assert it against another hardcoded json file in munit (mule 3.9 and dataweave 1). The issue is the payload show as "org.mule.munit.common.util.ReusableByteArrayInputStream@53534c15" under payload. When I convert it to java I can see the data, but not in json format. How can I extract the json in this byte array stream to be able to assert it against a json hardcoded file.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using the "Byte to String" block

[image]

Then, I have added the "Assert Equals" block, but made sure to format both values likes this.

```
#[payload.replaceAll("\\s+","")]

#[getResource('sample.json').asString().replaceAll("\\s+","")]
```

This did exactly what I needed.